# Socrata SoQL GraphQL

Tags: graphql, socrata

Anyone knows if Socrata has plans to add GraphQL to their stack? Attribute=value  querying + SoQL is very impressive and useful but GraphQL is starting available everywhere now.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't ruled it out, so maybe at some point in the future we will support GraphQL, but it's not currently on our roadmap. Awesome tech though!